# How do I update a field on one SharePoint 2013 list, based on another list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I recently created a holiday approval form and workflow on SharePoint. It works fine, however our HR department are having to update peoples "remaining days" as I cannot work out how to update this through the workflow.

I have an InfoPath form on SharePoint and use SharePoint designer for my workflow. What it is, is someone would request a holiday through the form. For example, lets say someone asked for 4 days off and they have a balance of 20 days. What we want is for this to update their "remaining days" to 16 whilst on Pending Approval.

If the holiday request is rejected, is it possible to then add the 4 back on... since these wont be used. So now their remaining days will be 20 days again.

If it is approved however, i would like for the "remaining days" to stay at 16.

I hope this makes sense. I have read through a lot of sites trying to find the answer, but SharePoint designer workflow goes beyond my understanding when I add "update list".

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that both **Balance** and the **number of requested days** are metadada, so in SharePoint Designer Workflows, first of all you should do the calculation using the action "Calculate":
[image]

After the calculation, you'll use the action "Update Item", to update the current item, and for the field "Balance" you set the output variable "calc" from the previous action:
[image]

Comment: I will give that a try. Thanks! Is it slightly more complicated to then add the days back on to requested days should the request be rejected? If so, since they are very rarely rejected, it may just be the case where we can manually update this field.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't subtract the days before the approval. If the request gets reject, you just do nothing with theses fields. If it gets approved, you do the calc. Just another approach, for you to think about, all of it could be done only with InfoPath. You can create an action that updates the Remaining Days field when the request gets approved. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, i think i made it very unclear in my first post. So i have 2 sharepoint lists, one holding employee information, and the other which is the holiday request form. Once the request is approved on list 1, i want the remaining days in list 2 to update, so next time they fill out a request it will show their remaining balance. As of right now, they put in a request and sometimes when they put in another request, HR havent updated their remaining days, so it says they still have 20 etc. My bad for not explaining that in the original post!!